# Net::SSLeay X509_STORE_add_cert function

Tags: perl, openssl, cryptography, rsa, x509

I'd like to use the newly-added `X509_verify_cert` function in `Net::SSLeay`, but am unable to put the low-level pieces together. This segfaults where marked. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Net::SSLeay;

# create a new BIO
my $cert_file = '/path/to/AppleIncRootCertificate.pem';
my $bio = Net::SSLeay::BIO_new_file($cert_file, 'r');

# make an x509 struct
my $x509 = Net::SSLeay::PEM_read_bio_X509($bio) || die "read_bio failed";
# returns: value corresponding to openssl's X509 structure (0 on failure)

my $store = Net::SSLeay::X509_STORE_CTX_new();

# segfaults here   \/ \/ \/ 
my $add_rv = Net::SSLeay::X509_STORE_add_cert($store, $x509);
# $store - value corresponding to openssl's X509_STORE structure
# $x509 - value corresponding to openssl's X509 structure

# next step?
# my $verify_rv = Net::SSLeay::X509_verify_cert(...?);
```

If I get that working, I'd like to the load the BIO from memory instead of going to the filesystem, and then get use the X509_verify_cert function

Documents are here:
http://search.cpan.org/~mikem/Net-SSLeay-1.85/lib/Net/SSLeay.pod#Low_level_API:_X509_STORE_*_related_functions

Answer (score 0):

If this is triggering a segmentation fault, then there is a bug `Net::SSLeay`. You should report the bug to the developers.